# Arabic Font Ellipsis issue in IE11

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am facing an issue with the ellipsis while using arabic font "Droid Arabic Kufi" on IE. This error occurs only on IE , however i fixed the issue on IE9, but the same code is not working on IE 11.

The error is when the page is rendered in IE11, instead of displaying the ellipsis dots (...) it is displaying boxes.

Please check the following JSFIDDLE example.

http://jsfiddle.net/qLrg92tb/1/

```
body{
    font-family : "Droid Arabic Kufi";
}
p{
    width:50px;
    text-overflow : ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden; 
    white-space: nowrap; 
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis; 
}

p:before{
 content : " ";
 font-family : "Arial";
}

p:after{
    content : " ";
     font-family : "Arial";
}
```

Waiting for any help.

Thanks

Comment: At least explain what the "error" or "issue" is.

Comment: I can see the issue even on IE10; windows 8.

Comment: It is problem related with the font "Droid arabic kufi" as explained [here](https://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/issues/detail?id=335).

Comment: until yesterday, i was running IE9, after using :before , it was working fine, but when i upgraded to IE 11 today, the issue came back again and it is not at all getting fixed. if you can help me tackling this issue. i would love to have a CSS solution

Comment: @Mr_Green : it is working well in Firefox / chrome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TypoThe Droid Arabic Kufi font does not contain the period “.” character (or any other Ascii characters for that matter, except the space), so when browsers implement `text-overflow: ellipsis`, they have to take the period from another font. Apparently some versions of IE fail to do that properly, possibly because they interpret the font information incorrectly (as if the font contained “.”).

A workaround is to put some suitable font before it in the the `font-family` list, so that “.” will be taken from it, e.g.

```
font-family : Verdana, "Droid Arabic Kufi";
```

This font should not contain Arabic characters, since the font takes precedence over anything mentioned later in the list. The font should also be available in all systems where IE is used. There is no absolute guarantee of this, but Verdana should be on all Windows systems unless it has been deliberately removed.

Technically this also means that the space character will be taken from that font, not from Droid Arabic Kufi. This may matter in spacing. In Droid Arabic Kufi, the advance width of the space is 696 units, in Verdana it is 700 units, so there should be no practical difference.

Comment: You have saved my life, Thank you!

Comment: But I noticed another problem appears after using this way, I have some sliders in the page, whenever the mouse moves over any place in the page, something changes the font to the initial one, this also happens only on IE8.